# how to pass the value dynamically to href in mail template using nodejs

Tags: node.js, html, email-templates

View Report

This is how my html template look like, whereas my nodejs code is

```
            templateContent = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, "utf8");
        templateContent = templateContent.replace("##ownername##", ownerObject.ownerName);
        templateContent = templateContent.replace("##link##", req.body.details.pdf.pdfUrl);
```

Comment: Here is the html template <a href="##link##" target="_blank">View Report</a>

Comment: It work fine using <p> tag,but not working with the <a> tag

Comment: Please next time edit your question instead of adding comments, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. Passing the  tag with the node.js file can solve this.
Example:

```
var link = "<a href='" +req.body.details.pdf.pdfUrl+ "'>Click Here</a>";
        templateContent = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, "utf8");
        templateContent = templateContent.replace("##ownername##", ownerObject.ownerName);
        templateContent = templateContent.replace("##link##", link);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also you `email-templates-v2` for rendering mail templates.

```
 const { EmailTemplate } = require('email-templates-v2');


const templateDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../../templates', 'template-name');
  const template = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    template.render({'link':'http://1.com'}, (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        const { html } = result;
        resolve(html);
      } else {
        logger.error(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

> create `templates` folder with `template-name` in folder.

```
templates
  email-verification
      html.ejs
```

> html.ejs

```
 <a href="<%= link %>" target="_blank">link</a>
```